# Split list created by re.findall to single words, then count occurrence of each word sorted descending by number of occurrences

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have to count the number of each word occurrence from each element of the list that iv created by re.findall.

For Example:
jobs = ["Java Developer","Data Scientist","Business Architect Process Mining","JavaScript Developer"]

jobs_split = ["Java","Developer","Data","Scientist","Business","Architect", "Process","Mining","JavaScript","Developer"]

Then count each of word occurrence and show it f.e. in file as Word: number of occurrences

I know that i can build in "Counter" in python, but tbh i don't know how to split all the elements in list

```
import urllib.request
import re
from collections import Counter

jobs = []
jobs_split = []

from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
for i in range(10):
    html = Request("https://mysite?pn={}".format(i), headers={'User-Agent':         'Mozilla/5.0'})
page = urlopen(html).read().decode('utf-8')

jobs += re.findall(r'"@type":"JobPosting","title":"([A-Za-z0-9 -/]+)","description"', page)

my_set = set(jobs)
# print(Counter(my_set))
print(my_set)
```

Comment: Could you add the expected output?

Comment: Developer: 2, Java: 1, Data: 1, Scientist: 1, Business: 1, Architect: 1, Process: 1, Mining: 1, JavaScript: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to join all words in one iterable:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

jobs = ["Java Developer","Data Scientist","Business Architect Process Mining","JavaScript Developer"]

tokens = chain.from_iterable(job.split() for job in jobs)
counts = Counter(tokens)

print(counts)
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'Developer': 2, 'JavaScript': 1, 'Architect': 1, 'Process': 1, 'Mining': 1, 'Business': 1, 'Scientist': 1, 'Java': 1, 'Data': 1})
```

Comment: It's exactly what i needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As simple as using `.split()` and splitting on the space `" "`

but have to iterate through your list:

```
jobs = ["Java Developer","Data Scientist","Business Architect Process Mining","JavaScript Developer"]

split = [ job.split() for job in jobs ]
jobs_split = [item for sublist in split for item in sublist]
```